# js & css versioning

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, caching, versioning

Knowing that I can version js and css files like

**Option 1:**

> myJavaScript.js?v=#myVersionNumber#
>   myCSS.css?v=#myVersionNumber#

,  This will make client to do a conditional GET request and best case scenario get a 304 response. I can eliminate this http request by a different versioning strategy like

**Option 2:**

> myJavaScript.#myVersionNumber#.js
>   myCSS.#myVersionNumber#.css

I am wondering if there are any good reasons (assuming that both options have the same level of maintainability), that will make me stay with Option1.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: A lot of frameworks and such are designed to be able to easily retrieve information from the query string. Other than that I'm not aware of any benefit. Basically more widespread adoption.

Answer (score 7):

I would argue that your not really versioning as much as controlling caching.  With the second approach I would be worried about storing multiple files in the source control systems, when if you stored a single file it will accumulate a history and can be managed easier.  You can then release the new file by changing the parameter in your url.

Comment: source control is a good additional perspective on the subject

Comment: i agree with your comments on this being related to cache controlling. I am aware of option 2 might have multiple files in source control if not implemented right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article that may help you regarding this issue...

[Automatically Version Your CSS and JavaScript Files](http://www.particletree.com/notebook/automatically-version-your-css-and-javascript-files/)

This code is in php, and some modifications in .htaccess file of your website, which may need some more attention otherwise your site may breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the simplest option myJavascript-1.js ?   And, just bump that number in both the filename and the source that loads it every time you rev the file?  No query string required.  Cache is always defeated when you release a new version.

There are sometimes reasons to leave the old version still available to avoid a client with a cached HTML page ever getting mixed versions of old and new among several different files and this allows both new and old to easily exist in the file system on your server at the same time (if desired).